HP MR Storage - storcli64.exe tool suddenly fails to detect controller
I have an HP server running windows 2022 which has a HPE MR408i-o Gen11 raid controller.
I have an automated script which periodically runs the following command
storcli64.exe /c0 show all
and which checks the output for things like array status, battery status, cache status, etc.
It normally works well. However I've recentely seen an issue where the tool returns the following
CLI Version = 007.2417.0000.0000 Apr 21, 2023
Operating system = Windows Server 2022
Status Code = 0
Status = Success
Description = None

Number of Controllers = 0
Host Name = MYSERVER
Operating System  = Windows Server 2022
StoreLib IT Version = 07.2403.0200.0000
StoreLib IR3 Version = 16.14-0

The gui(web) tool reports that the controller is working fine.
This occured a couple of months back and the tool went back to reporting normally before I could investigate it. This time I caught it a after my script alerted me.
My next course of action is going to be to update the tool and drivers, but this is going to require downtime for a load of boxes as this is a vm host.
Anyone seen a similar issue? Any idea whats going on?
